# [не работает]Регулярное выражение(replace) на русском?

Tags: javascript

Имею код в php шаблоне.

```
//slug
                    title = title.toLowerCase();
                    title = title.replace(/[^\w ]+/g, '');
                    title = title.replace(/ +/g, '-');
```

Работает с англ. буквами вот так .Удаляет русский и в место пробела ставит"-".

```
FFFFFF gggggg 5555
ffffff-gggggg-5555
```

Хочу сделать чтобы работало с русским. Перепробовал разные варианты с /u,/i,/iu
не работает . Подскажите как заставить в php работать. Может прописать в странице жесткую привязку в кодировке ?

Вот мои примеры которые я пробовал.

```
//slug
                    title = title.toLowerCase();
                    title = title.replace(/[^А-Яа-яЁё]+/iu, '');
                    title = title.replace(/ +/iu, '-'); 
//slug
                    title = title.toLowerCase();
                    title = title.replace(/[^\w ]+/u, '');
                    title = title.replace(/ +/u, '-');
//slug
                    title = title.toLowerCase();
                    title = title.replace(/[^\w ]+/ug, '');
                    title = title.replace(/ +/ug, '-'); 
 //slug
                    title = title.toLowerCase();
                    title = title.replace(/[^А-Яа-яЁё]+/i, '');
                    title = title.replace(/ +/i, '-');
```

Comment: может напишите что у вас на входе за строка, и желаемый результат? и собственно при чем тут `php` если код на js.

Comment: Да действительно это script type="text/javascript спасибо что поправили 
выше я указал 
FFFFFF gggggg 5555
ffffff-gggggg-5555
аналогично должно работать и на русском

Comment: Новая информация , залил сайт на хостинг работает как надо . даже без правок . Из коробки . И теперь стоит вопрос что не так с локальным сервером . Использую OpenServer

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pst6wc 

https://prnt.sc/pst752
Вот настройки сервера , на хостинге ниже стоит php

Comment: в javascript `\w` только для латинских букв

Comment: и кaкое решение ?

Comment: этот ява вставлен в php

Comment: `/[^а-яё]+/i` - вполне хватит, чтобы выбрать все, что не является русскими буквами